# How to `create a setuid copy` of some command?

Tags: setuid

I am reading the book `How Linux Works` and there is something I do not understand:

> On normal Linux systems, most processes have the same `effective user
>   ID` and `real user ID`. By default, `ps` and other system diagnostic
>   programs show the `effective user ID`. To view both the effective and
>   real user IDs on your system, try this, but don’t be surprised if you
>   find that the two user ID columns are identical for all processes on
>   your system:

```
$ ps -eo pid,euser,ruser,comm
```

> To create an exception just so that you can see different values in
>   the columns, try experimenting by creating a setuid copy of the `sleep`
>   command, running the copy for a few seconds, and then running the
>   preceding `ps` command in another window before the copy terminates.

The author said: `try experimenting by creating a setuid copy of ...`, but how to create a setuid copy of the `sleep` command? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a copy in a location from which you could run it (i.e. filesystems mounted with `noexec` don't qualify). This is `/tmp/` in my example.

```
sudo cp /bin/sleep /tmp/
```

(I used `sudo` to ensure the copy belongs to `root` from the very beginning; this saves me `sudo chown …` later). **The following command [sets setuid bit for the file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/175711/108618):**

```
sudo chmod u+s /tmp/sleep
```

Now run it in background as a regular user:

```
/tmp/sleep 300 &
```

Then check the output of `ps`:

```
ps -eo pid,euser,ruser,comm | grep sleep
```

The result is `euser` points to the file owner, `ruser` points to the user that executes.

<sub>Note: while playing with setuid, keep in mind [it doesn't work with scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/108618).</sub>